# Error 404 undefined on a deployed page on Vercel using NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I created a next JS app, Upon deployment, I tried going to subpages, I had a few, for example /reservations, upon reaching that route, I get a error message saying error 404 page not found, I tried replicating it in terminal using the npm run build function, I got the following error
[image: Error message.]

This is the file structure
[image: File structure]

I suppose it is a middleware error, so adding middleware.ts code for refrence

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"

export const config={
    matcher:[
        "/trips",
        "/favorites",
        "/reservations",
        "/pets"

    ]
}
```

Although, While using the website in a dev enviorment, the website and the pages work just fine, so there is no error with API calling, What could possibly be wrong?